# R factor levels

Tags: r, types

I have imported data which is reading in decimal numbers as factors.
In the data some values are blank, and some are " - " for zero.
I want to convert the field into a numeric, so i thought i should replace the "" with NA, and the " - " with "0"
How can I do this?  I prefer not to change the read.csv command, but instead be able to edit the vector.

```
data = read.csv(pathtofile)
x <- data$x
class(x)
x[""] <- NA
x[" - "] <- "0"
data$x <- x
```

`x[" - "] <- "0"` gives the warning 
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, " - ", value = "0") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: Try `read.csv(file, na.strings = "", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` then do `data$x[data$x == " - "] <- 0; data$x <- as.numeric(data$x)`

Comment: @RichardScriven but then you can't tell the difference between "" and " - " to assign them different values

Comment: Refresh to see the updated comment.  I think it will do all of it